# iOS 8 Dismiss keyboard for swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios8, keyboard

i'm a beginner in swift and i have been using this `dismissKeyboard()` method but it is not working for the keyboard extension.

```
@IBAction func donePressed (sender: UIButton) {

      dismissKeyboard()


    }
```

can anyone tell me why this doesn't work?

thanks.

EDIT: full code

import UIKit

class KeyboardViewController: UIInputViewController {

```
var keyboardView: UIView!

@IBOutlet var nextKeyboardButton: UIButton!

override func updateViewConstraints() {
    super.updateViewConstraints()

    // Add custom view sizing constraints here
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

  self.loadInterface()





}


func loadInterface() {

    var keyboardNib = UINib(nibName: "KeyboardView", bundle: nil)

    self.keyboardView = keyboardNib.instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil)[0] as UIView

    view.addSubview(self.keyboardView)

    view.backgroundColor = self.keyboardView.backgroundColor

    self.nextKeyboardButton.addTarget(self, action: "advanceToNextInputMode", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

    self.nextKeyboardButton.addTarget(self, action: "advanceToNextInputMode", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated
}

override func textWillChange(textInput: UITextInput) {
    // The app is about to change the document's contents. Perform any preparation here.
}

override func textDidChange(textInput: UITextInput) {
    // The app has just changed the document's contents, the document context has been updated.

}

@IBAction func buttonPressed (sender: UIButton) {

    let title = sender.titleForState(.Normal)

    var proxy = textDocumentProxy as UITextDocumentProxy

    proxy.insertText(title!)

}

@IBAction func spacePressed (sender: UIButton) {

    var proxy = textDocumentProxy as UITextDocumentProxy

    proxy.insertText(" ")

}

@IBAction func deletePressed (sender: UIButton) {

    var proxy = textDocumentProxy as UITextDocumentProxy

    proxy.deleteBackward()

}

@IBAction func donePressed (sender: UIButton) {

resignFirstResponder()


}
```

}

Comment: resignFirstResponder() call this method instead of dismissKeyboard() but you need to call with the textFieldDemo.resignFirstResponder() like that....

Where is your instance of textField.....

Comment: There is no text field, its just a custom keyboard for the iphone

Comment: ok you simply call resignFirstResponder() and let me know

Comment: i tried using it in safari and the calendar

Comment: it didn't work , the resignFirstResponder()

Comment: can you post full code so that it is easy to analys in calender why did you enable the keyboard ?

Comment: it is a code i got from a tutorial on youtube but I'm trying to modify for my own purposes.

Comment: i edited the question, the code will now be visible.

Comment: try self.dismissKeyboard()

Comment: oh wait, it just did work!!!!! FINALLY! thanks man... if there is any way i can upvote your account tell me cause I'm new here.

Comment: i tried self.dismissKeyboard() before and it didn't work, i tried it now and it did. sometime i face this issue where it doesn't work from the first time.

Answer (score 1):

Try like that

`self.dismissKeyboard()`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try :

```
view.endEditing(true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Dismisses the custom keyboard from the screen.

**Swift:**

```
self.dismissKeyboard()
```

**Objective-C:**

```
[self dismissKeyboard];
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiinputviewcontroller/1618196-dismisskeyboard?language=objc